# Unable to propagate container ERROR in shared namespace pod containing sidecar containers

Tags: shell, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes pod with two containers running with a shared namespace. First container is primary container executing job and second container is a sidecar container with only tail command.

COMMAND in container 1:

```
python <some_script> > out.log
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ERROR_OCCURED=1
fi
pkill tail;
if [ -z ${ERROR_OCCURED+x} ]; then echo "Program Success"; else exit 1; fi;
```

COMMAND in container 2:

```
/bin/sh -c tail -n+1 -f out.log;
true
```

Now when im trying to put error in both container by setting exit status. jobs are getting completed state or one pod keep running.

Tried Approach 1:

```
killall `ps -e | grep sh | awk '{print $1}'`
```

1. Container 1
   State:          Terminated
   Reason:         Error
2. Container 2
   **State:          RUNNING**

Pod Status ---> Error 1/2

```
testerror-7c712448-a254-4dd0-a1eb-b99016f00007-abc-qqsgp   1/2     Error         0          56m
```

Tried Approach 2:

```
pkill tail
```

1. Container 1
   State:          Terminated
   Reason:         Error
2. Container 2
   State:          Terminated
   **Reason:         Completed**

Pod Status ---> Completed 0/2

```
NAME                                                       READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
testerror-7c712448-a254-4dd0-a1eb-b99016f00007-abc-qqsgp   0/2     Completed   0          5m12s
```

What I want to achieve is error with no container in running status

```
ERROR 0/2

Container 1 State: Terminated Reason: Error
Container 2 State: Terminated Reason: Error


NAME                                                       READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
testerror-7c712448-a254-4dd0-a1eb-b99016f00007-abc-qqsgp   0/2     Error   0          5m12s
```

Comment: Could you configure a LivenessProbe to achieve that?

Comment: Adding livness probe will give error 2/2 but i will not able to get complete 2/2 status.

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? It's a bit hard to understand what you want to achieve.